# Compare new value with previous average in Spark Streaming

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have created a window in Spark Streaming with 5 integer values. Each time one second passes, the window gets 1 new value and looses the oldest.
Each time a new value comes, I calculate the average of the values in the window like this:

```
 JavaDStream<Integer> average = values.map(new Function<Integer, Integer>() {
      @Override
      public Integer call(Integer a) throws Exception {
          int b = a/5;


          return b;


  } });
```

So the average keeps changing.

The problem is, each time a new value comes to the window, I want to compare it to the previous average. If this new value is much bigger or smaller than the average, I want to drop it and keep the old average. If not, the avarage can be updated.

My question is, how can I store this 'old average', so I can compare it with the new value in the window?

Thank you.

Comment: Are calculating the average based on a key? Or simply processing a stream of incoming integers?

Comment: One way to store it and retrieve it for comparison would be to use one of the various datastore's either integrated with Spark Streaming or packaged with a Spark connector. Examples are [SnappyData](https://github.com/SnappyDataInc/snappydata), [Redis](https://github.com/RedisLabs/spark-redis), [MemSQL](https://github.com/memsql/memsql-spark-connector), [Cassandra](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector), [HBase](https://github.com/nerdammer/spark-hbase-connector)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, it's the second case exactly, I'm processing a stream of integers (5 arrive per second), and using `map` methods to calculate the mean of these integers

Answer (score 0):

You could try something similar to the following:

1. create a "key-value DStream" with a pseudo key (e.g. 1)
2. use mapWithState() to store the last average and compare as you mentioned; return the average you want to use further

it could look like the following:

```
JavaPairDStream<Integer, Integer> pairedIntStream = values.mapToPair(
new PairFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
      @Override
      public Tuple2<Integer, Integer> call(Integer a) throws Exception {
          return new Tuple2<Integer, Integer>(1, a);
} });

Function3<Integer, Optional<Integer>, State<Integer>, Integer> mappingFunction =
       new Function3<Integer, Optional<Integer>, State<Integer>, Integer>() {
           @Override
           public Integer call(Integer s, Optional<Integer> value, State<Integer> state) {

              int avg = value.orNull() / 5;

              if(!state.exists() || state.get() < avg) {
                  state.update(avg);
                  return avg;
              }
              return state.get();
           }
       };

    JavaMapWithStateDStream<Integer, Integer, Integer, Integer> mapWithStateDStream =
        pairedIntStream.mapWithState(StateSpec.function(mappingFunc));
```